# How to import cdn file in blazor C# code?

Tags: c#, blazor, cdn

Is there any way to import cdn file with InvokeAsync?

```cs
JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js");
```

When I am trying to import cdn file with InvokeAsync it throws an error:

> Access to script at 'https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js' from origin 'http://localhost:5170' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I want to import this cdn only for a one-page view, for example on page "/" I want to have this cdn file but on "/counter" it must be disabled.

Comment: What if you directly use the url in script tag?

Comment: The site amcharts.com don't allow the access. Look at CORS security https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @Chetan I just tried to add script directly in my page view `<script suppress-error="BL9992" src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>`, not sure if it is a good practice but it works.